# A fallacy about join and meet

Tags: lattice-orders

We know that (as per the general definition of $\wedge$)

> $x\wedge y=x$ in a lattice $(L,\le)$

Again $\wedge $ being commutative in $L$, we have

> $x\wedge y=y\wedge x=y$, by definition.

So what we find is that the lub of two distinct elements $x$ and $y$ are different. How is this possible?

So what I am assuming that in a lattice, $x\wedge y\ne y\wedge x$, i.e $\wedge$ is not commutative but this is also contradicting the definition of lattice (or algebraic lattice, since there there is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between lattice ordered set and algebraic lattice).

So what's happening here?

Comment: Where is $x\land y=x$ coming from? You are assuming it, but, generally, of course, it is not true. It is true if and only if $x\le y$. Take an example of the set $\mathbb N$ with $\le$, and $x\land y=\min(x,y), x\lor y=\max(x,y)$.

Comment: yes i understand @StinkingBishop

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with your "general definition".  In fact, I would say
$$
x \wedge y = x\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x \le y
$$

Comment: yes i understand... thanks